# Dense Set of Functions

Tags: uniform-convergence, function-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let $(\mathcal{F}_0,\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty)$ be a metric space of continuous functions that is dense in the space $\mathcal{F}$. Is the following statement correct:

> For every $f\in\mathcal{F}$, there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{F}_0$ that converges uniformly to $f$.

Specifically, I wonder if we can demand *uniform convergence*?

Comment: Of course that depends on in what topology you're referring to when you say "dense." If you mean dense in the topology of uniform convergence then this is true more or less by definition. Otherwise what do you mean by "dense"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your help. I have no background in topology. My question relates to reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (RKHS), where the linear span of the kernel functions is dense in the RKHS (see e.g. Prop 3.1 in https://www.math.uh.edu/~vern/rkhs.pdf). Do we have uniform convergence in any RKHS?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe I should add that $\sup_{x\in\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{K(x,x)} < \infty$ implies the following: Convergence with respect to $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\mathcal{H}_K}$ implies convergence with respect to $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$. Is it correct that covergence in the sup-norm then established uniform convergence.

Comment: Looking at the notes cited in your comment (the info there should be put into your question) and the prerequisites for [MATH 6395: Operators on Hilbert Spaces](https://uh.edu/nsm/_docs/math/graduate/courses/grad_courseSpring2006.htm) when taught by Paulsen, and your background, I recommend the first few chapters (and maybe selected later sections) of [**Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471504599) by Erwin Kreyszig (1978; reprinted in 1989). Note that it has 143 reviews at amazon.com, which is pretty impressive for a math text at this level.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the advice, I will have a look at the suggested book.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a freely available copy [here](https://archive.org/details/introductory-functional-analysis-with-applications), which thus far seems to have escaped notice [here](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Kreyszig%2C+Erwin%22) due to a (intentional?) misspelling of the author's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Qiaochu Yuan and @Dave L. Renfro for the helpful advice. From what I have learnt, I think I can answer my question as follows:

Assume that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ with respect to $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$, that is, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$
\begin{equation}
\Vert f_n - f\Vert_\infty = \sup_{x\in\mathcal{X}} \vert f_n(x) - f(x)\vert < \varepsilon
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\forall\,\varepsilon > 0, \exists\,N\in\mathbb{N} : \forall\,n > N, x\in\mathcal{X}\qquad\vert f_n(x) - f(x)\vert < \varepsilon
\end{equation}
which coincides with the definition of uniform convergence. To conclude, we realize that $\mathcal{F}_0$ being dense in $\mathcal{F}$ and convergence in the sup-norm imply uniform convergence of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{F}_0$ to $f\in\mathcal{F}$.